# Awaiting for an async action creator to update the state inside another action creator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have an [action creator](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-7-standard-patterns#action-creators) that performs an async request and updates the state (using react-redux middleware):

```
export function requestA() {
  return function (dispatch) {
    dispatch(startRequest())
    return Service.getA().then(
      data => dispatch(receivedA(data)),
      error => console.log("An error occurred.", error)
    )
  }
}
```

That works fine.
Now I want to create another action creator, that will use the `requestA()` action creator, and will call another async request.

```
export function requestB() {
  return function (dispatch, getState) {
    dispatch(requestA()) // <--- How to await for this ???
    let A_data = getState().A_data;
    return Service.getB(A_data).then(
      data => dispatch(receivedB(data)),
      error => console.log("An error occurred.", error)
    )
  }
}
```

Is there a way for me to await for the `dispatch(requestA())` to complete before I continue to run the rest of the function?
I need the state to be updated before I continue to the next request.

**Note**
I know I could do this by calling the 2 requests in my action creator, but I want to know if I can do it calling the `dispatch(requestA())` , as the logic for that is already set.

Comment: Did you try adding `.then` after `dispatch(requestA())` ?

Comment: Thanks ! Didn't know it returned a promise !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to wait for the call function to finish using `await` `async` keywords:

```js
export function requestA() {
  return async function (dispatch) {
    dispatch(startRequest())
    await Service.getA().then(
      data => dispatch(receivedA(data)),
      error => console.log("An error occurred.", error)
    )
  }
}
```